# Return IEnumerable of DTOs including many-to-many mapping in single SQL SELECT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core

I am using Automapper to project from an EF Core 2 entity to a DTO. My query returns an IEnumerable of DTO instances. One of the properties on my DTO is an IEnumerable that is populated via a many-to-many relationship off of the source entity. The solution laid out below works, however it results in many individual SQL `SELECT` queries.

Is there a way to map the many-to-many where EF can compile a single `SELECT` query rather than `n` queries?

TSource:

```
public class FilterList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FilterListLanguage> FilterListLanguages { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ViewUrl { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

TDestination:

```
public class FilterListSummaryDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Languages { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ViewUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Profile:

```
CreateMap<FilterList, FilterListSummaryDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Languages,
        conf => conf.MapFrom(list => list.FilterListLanguages.Select(x => x.Language.Name)));
```

Query:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<FilterListSummaryDto>> GetAllSummariesAsync()
{
    return await filterListsDbContext.FilterLists
                                     .AsNoTracking()
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                                     .ProjectTo<FilterListSummaryDto>()
                                     .ToListAsync();
}
```

Example SQL Queries Executed:

```
...
SELECT `x.Language`.`Name`
FROM `filterlists_languages` AS `x0`
INNER JOIN `languages` AS `x.Language` ON `x0`.`LanguageId` = `x.Language`.`Id`
WHERE @_outer_Id = `x0`.`FilterListId`
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@_outer_Id='82' (DbType = UInt16)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `x.Language`.`Name`
FROM `filterlists_languages` AS `x0`
INNER JOIN `languages` AS `x.Language` ON `x0`.`LanguageId` = `x.Language`.`Id`
WHERE @_outer_Id = `x0`.`FilterListId`
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@_outer_Id='86' (DbType = UInt16)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `x.Language`.`Name`
FROM `filterlists_languages` AS `x0`
INNER JOIN `languages` AS `x.Language` ON `x0`.`LanguageId` = `x.Language`.`Id`
WHERE @_outer_Id = `x0`.`FilterListId`
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@_outer_Id='85' (DbType = UInt16)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
...
```

Comment: If you remove ProjectTo and instead do a select, does it still give the same output?

Comment: This is current EF Core defect. See [EF Core 2.1 Stretch goals](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#stretch-goals) -> [Reduce n+1 queries](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9282)

Comment: Have you tried an include for FilterListLanguages `.Include(x => x.FilterListLanguages)`?

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara yes, it does.

Comment: @Brad I tried that. And I also tried a ThenInclude with the other entity of the m-to-m. no dice.

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev . Sadness, but that must be the answer at this point.